# Regular Expression with no LookBehind feature

Tags: qt, qregexp

I am trying to write a regular expression that looks for all ';' characters that isn't followed by a NEW LINE (\n) character.

```
;(?!\\\n)
```

and all NEW LINE (\n) characters that is not preceded by a ';' character:

```
(?< !;)\\\n
```

Unfortunately I am using Qt 4.7.4 QRegExp and it does not support "Look Behind".  How do I rewrite the regular expression above so it doesn't use "Look Behind"?

Answer (score 1):

Quoting from the documentation:

http://doc.qt.digia.com/4.7/qregexp.html#details

> Both zero-width positive and zero-width negative lookahead assertions (?=pattern) and (?!pattern) are supported with the same syntax as Perl.

What is probably happening is that you are running on a Windows machine that has inserted `\r\n` instead of just a `\n`... or maybe it was a text file created on a windows machine.

One thing to watch out for, that I found out for lookbehinds, is that you can't have a variable length lookbehind with most regex handlers out there.

If lookbehinds/lookaheads are still giving you trouble, the other option to look into is using capture groups, and then refer only to the capture group you are interested in.

From the [code-examples section](http://doc.qt.digia.com/4.7/qregexp.html#code-examples) of the docs it has this:

```
str = "Nokia Corporation\tqt.nokia.com\tNorway";
QString company, web, country;
rx.setPattern("^([^\t]+)\t([^\t]+)\t([^\t]+)$");
if (rx.indexIn(str) != -1) {
    company = rx.cap(1);
    web = rx.cap(2);
    country = rx.cap(3);
}
```

A capture group is defined with parenthesis and is later access by its index starting at 1.  The zeroth index is the entire match (not broken into capture groups).

http://doc.qt.digia.com/4.7/qregexp.html#cap

http://doc.qt.digia.com/4.7/qregexp.html#capturedTexts

Hope that helps.  Regular Expressions can be a lot of fun when they are working right.  Good luck.

I also like using this [tool](http://gskinner.com/RegExr/).  The formatting may be a little different from QRegEx, but it is pretty quick to translate and test once you have it.

UPDATE:
Here is a full suite, showing off 4 different capture strings and what they find with QRegEx:

```
#include <QCoreApplication>
#include <QRegExp>
#include <QString>
#include <QDebug>
#include <QStringList>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QCoreApplication a(argc, argv);

    QString str =
            "This is a long string;\n"
            "with some semi colons;\n"
            "sometimes followed by a new line;\n"
            "and other times followed; by something else.\n"

            "(;)([^\\n]) find a semicolon and a new line\n"
            "(;)(?!\\n)  find a semicolon not followed by a new line, negative look-ahead\n"

            "([^;])(\\n) find a non semicolon and a new line\n"
            "(?<!;)(\\n) find a new line, not preceeded by a semicolon.\n";

    QList <QRegExp> rx_list;

    QRegExp rx_colon_and_non_newline;
    rx_colon_and_non_newline.setPattern("(;)([^\\n])");

    QRegExp rx_colon_and_neg_lookahead;
    rx_colon_and_neg_lookahead.setPattern("(;)(?!\\n)");

    QRegExp rx_non_colon_and_newline;
    rx_non_colon_and_newline.setPattern("([^;])(\\n)");

    QRegExp rx_neg_lookbehind_and_newline;
    rx_neg_lookbehind_and_newline.setPattern("(?<!;)(\\n)");

    rx_list << rx_colon_and_non_newline
            << rx_colon_and_neg_lookahead
            << rx_non_colon_and_newline
            << rx_neg_lookbehind_and_newline;

    foreach(QRegExp rx, rx_list)
    {
        int count = 0;
        int pos = 0;
        qDebug() << "Pattern" << rx.pattern();
        while ((pos = rx.indexIn(str, pos)) != -1) {
            QStringList capturedTexts(rx.capturedTexts());

            for(int i = 0; i<capturedTexts.size(); i++)
                capturedTexts[i].replace('\n',"\\n");

            qDebug() << "\t" << count << "Found at position" << pos << capturedTexts;
            // qDebug() << rx.cap();
            pos += rx.matchedLength();
            ++count;
        }
        if(count == 0)
            qDebug() << "\tNo matches found.";
    }


    return a.exec();
}
```

output:

```
Pattern "(;)([^\n])"
         0 Found at position 104 ("; ", ";", " ")
         1 Found at position 126 (";)", ";", ")")
         2 Found at position 169 (";)", ";", ")")
         3 Found at position 247 (";]", ";", "]")
         4 Found at position 295 (";)", ";", ")")
Pattern "(;)(?!\n)"
         0 Found at position 104 (";", ";")
         1 Found at position 126 (";", ";")
         2 Found at position 169 (";", ";")
         3 Found at position 247 (";", ";")
         4 Found at position 295 (";", ";")
Pattern "([^;])(\n)"
         0 Found at position 123 (".\n", ".", "\n")
         1 Found at position 166 ("e\n", "e", "\n")
         2 Found at position 242 ("d\n", "d", "\n")
         3 Found at position 289 ("e\n", "e", "\n")
         4 Found at position 347 (".\n", ".", "\n")
Pattern "(?<!;)(\n)"
        No matches found.
```

Comment: i wonder, shouldn't this answer be accepted. I agree totally that using capture groups is better than using look-behind/ahead in my opinion. The only real reason I ever use the LA/LB is when dealing with grep on the command line when I need to filter something quickly, and maybe occasionally in scripting with GREP or SED, other than that i don't use it, not even with Perl since at that point it no longer makes sense to not use captures. Also, negative look-behinds suck anyway because they have to be fixed length; which is annoying when you don't know exactly how long the string is going to be!

Comment: It took me quite a while to first find out about the inability to use variable length look-behinds.  I thought I was going crazy.  I probably should revisit this answer, and put a full test and solution, showing how it should be done.  Here is more of my answers on the subject: http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=user%3A999943+qregex

Answer (score 0):

> Perl's lookbehind assertions, "independent" subexpressions and conditional expressions are not supported.

From http://doc.qt.io/archives/qt-4.8/qregexp.html

So the `(?<;!;)\n` does not work 
and the `(?!;)\n` will match all new line characters
 regardless of whether they are preceded by a `;`